# show progress of running scripts using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, batch-file

I need to show the progress of , a bunch of running batch files in a specific sequence using a powershell script. Lets say there are 10 batch files:- 1.bat, 2.bat and so on upto 10.bat. The progress of the bar should increment when 1.bat is executed , then it should increment when 2.bat gets executed and progress bar should reach 100% when 10.bat gets executed.So far i have been able to create a progress bar using powershell. How to link the progress of those batch files with this progress bar? any pointers in this direction will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

# Init Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = "**OSP Installation in Progress**"

# Init ProgressBar
$pbrTest = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$pbrTest.Maximum = 100
$pbrTest.Minimum = 0
$pbrTest.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
$pbrTest.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(967,10)
$i = 0
$Form.Controls.Add($pbrTest)

# Show Form
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Any reason for using forms.progress bar? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849902.aspx sounds like a good solution

Comment: If you want to show progress in a form you need to create some action (i.e. `OnLoad`) and increment progress bar there within `foreach` loop. OR (as a much better solution) not use a form and use `Write-Progress` as suggested above.

Comment: @Deptor To show a GUI based progress bar to the user.I had tried Write_Progress initially but felt forms.progress bar shows a better GUI for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
$batches = Get-Item 'D:\Soft\Scripts\testbat\*.bat'

# Init Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = "**OSP Installation in Progress**"

# Init ProgressBar
$pbrTest = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$pbrTest.Maximum = $batches.Count
$pbrTest.Minimum = 0
$pbrTest.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
$pbrTest.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(967,10)
$Form.Controls.Add($pbrTest)

# Add_Shown action    
$ShownFormAction = {
    $Form.Activate()

    foreach ($b in $batches) {
        $pbrTest.Increment(1)
        Start-Process $b.FullName -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
    }
    $Form.Dispose()
}
$Form.Add_Shown($ShownFormAction)

# Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Why not just use `Write-Progress`?

Comment: According to the OP, the sequence matters for these files. `Get-Item` should be `Get-ChildItem` with an appropriate `sort-object`